# Is there an easy way to swap an array of objects for an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I just wrote this whole program using a bunch of array of classes.  One for example is:

```
private Cat casts[] = new Cat[numOfCats];
```

and was recently informed by my teacher that we need to be using `ArrayList`.

Now the assignment is almost due and I'm looking for a quick way to resolve this. From what I have read online I would create the list like this:

```
ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>(numOfCats);
```

What I am wondering is how do I access setters and getters of the `new ArrayList cats`?  From what I can find it would be something like `cats get(i).getLocation().x;` or `cats get(i).setSize(100);` but neither of those are working.

Thank you for your time and I hope to hear back from you shortly!

Comment: Please show your code and how these are not working. Unfortunately my crystal ball is out of order today.

Comment: Looks like you may be missing a `.` -- try using `cats.get(i)` to get the `Cat` instance at position `i` in the collection (rather that `cats get(i)`).

Comment: Yes, you were right, neuronaut. I was following a guide online and they didn't have a `.` there so I didn't know I need one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is a wrapper class for dynamically resizing array. While plain array provides only "setter", "getter" and "length" methods, `ArrayList` provides this and much more.

Suppose, you have `Cat [] catArray`  and `List<Cat> catList`. (See below, why `List` and not `ArrayList`).

1. Setter: instead of `catArray[i] = someCat` use `catList.set(i, someCat)`
2. Getter: instead of `someCat = catArray[i]` use `someCat = catList.get(i)`. Getter returns `Cat`, so you can call methods on returned object as this: `catList.get(i).meow();`
3. Size:  `catArray.length` becomes `catList.size()`

List also provides such methods as `add` (insert element at position or append to the end of the list),  `remove` (delete element from list),  `indexOf` to search element, etc.

The biggest advantage of `ArrayList` comparing to plain array is that it is resizable. You don't need to specify fixed size in advance, `ArrayList` will grow as you add elements and shrink as you remove them.

This resizing nature of List also implies the main difference between these two structures. When working with Arrays, you used to create array of fixed length and then set it's elements one by one:

```
Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];
for (int i = 0; i < cats.length; i ++) {
   cats[i] = new Cat(); // populate cat #i
}
```

With lists you usually create empty list and then add elements to it. You don't need to care about size, as list grows as you add elements:

```
List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
// we want to add 10 cats
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
   cats.add(new Cat()); //add new cat to the end of the list
}
```

Regarding the declaration `List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();`. In java it is considered good practice to declare variable as the least concrete interface as practical. For lists it's usually `Collection` or `List`. However it will not be a mortal mistake if you declare your `cats` as `ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();`

I intentionally omitted many aspects of Arrays vs Lists, including primitives, performance, generics. Internet [is full](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/03/difference-between-array-and-arraylist-in-java-example.html) of [articles](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/04/11/3-good-reasons-to-avoid-arrays-in-java-interfaces/) that can provide more details if OP is interested.

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah one of the big parts was that I was not putting the . But your other things listed helped a lot as well.  Oh and thanks for making my post look better haha.

Answer (score 0):

To add an element to the ArrayList use the method `add`, for example: `cats.add(new Cat())`; and to get an element use the method `get`, for example `cats.get(index);` 
where index is the position of the Cat object in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arraylist<String> cats = new Arraylist();//using string for easier understanding

cats.get (i);//will get the string object at index i
cats.add ("hi");
cats.add (new String ("world!");//will add a new string to the list. If your using an arraylist note that it will not be sorted in any way
```

That's how you get indexes from an arraylist.

Just as a side note: use `java.util.List` rather than arraylist as you can change the type later.

Comment: This suggestions has a bit of code smell to it. It's not a good idea to create an ArrayList instance without a type parameter (i.e. `ArrayList<Cat>` is preferable). And suggesting to put different object types such as `Cat` and `String` into the same collection is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Im so sorry. Having issues with my phone. Will fix it now